# Close all UI bootstrap modals on route change before controller loads (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

Code for modal closing ([from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762323/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-close-angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-when-route-chan)):

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', x => $uibModalStack.dismissAll("location change dismiss all"));
```

This listener is simply created once on app run and it properly closes all modals when location is changed. However, my problem is that it does it AFTER a controller is loaded from the new route, which is creating a modal:

```
app.controller(..., function(...){
...
dialog.create(template, 'DocumentSearchDialogController', {groups: documentGroups, callback: callback}, 'lg')
```

(where `dialog` is a simple wrapper for `$uibModal`)
So the modal is created and then instantly closed by the listener. I don't want that - I want the listener to clear modals *before* the controller creates the modal.
I've found one work-around: wrapping the modal creation in `$timeout(..., 0)` delays it to the next digest/apply, which happens after both controller and listener executed all their code. This isn't ideal - I'd like to simply clear modals before initializing controllers and, ideally, not touch any controller at all.
Edit: I am using UI-Router.

Comment: is your modal created on new page or from the previous page?

Comment: On new page, and only given specific state params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the listener I used is suboptimal when UI-Router is in use. In fact, I cannot even prevent the state change in my listener.
Instead, when using UI-Router, `$transitions.onStart()` should be used for listening to state changes.

Comment: More about Transitions: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitions